# Getting NULL values while parsing URL string in Android

Tags: android, string, parsing, url, referrer

I am getting URL string in below loop

```
  referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
```

Following is Log

```
action: 'com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER' referrer string: 'utm_source=tooyoou&utm_medium=banner&utm_term=foursquare&utm_content=foursquare-tooyoou&utm_campaign=foursquare'
```

I want to Parse this URL string and get below strings
"utm_source"
"utm_medium"
"utm_term"
"utm_content"
"utm_campaign"

I tried below code but getting value null

```
Uri referrerUri = Uri.parse(referrer);
String utmsource= referrerUri.getQueryParameter("utm_source");
String utmmedium= referrerUri.getQueryParameter("utm_medium");
String utmterm= referrerUri.getQueryParameter("utm_term");
String utmcontent= referrerUri.getQueryParameter("utm_content");
String utmcampaign= referrerUri.getQueryParameter("utm_campaign");


Log.d("utmsource===" , utmsource);
Log.d("utmmedium===" , utmmedium);
Log.d("utmterm===" , utmterm);
Log.d("utmcontent===" , utmcontent);
Log.d("utmcampaign===" , utmcampaign);
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: URI should be according to rfc2396, please try Uri.parse("http://localhost?" + referrer); by concating schema and domain name

Answer (score 4):

You can use `split`..

```
String[] referrerList = referrer.split('&');
String utmsource= referrerList[0].substring(referrerList[0].indexOf("=") + 1);
String utmmedium= referrerList[1].substring(referrerList[1].indexOf("=") + 1);
String utmterm= referrerList[2].substring(referrerList[2].indexOf("=") + 1);
....
```

Comment: Thanks Nunu, You mean i need not to Parse ? Can I use direct "split" ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this, instead of parsing that `String` as an `URI`.

```
String[] uriTokens = referrer.split("&");
for(int i=0;i<uriTokens.length;i++){
    String[] valTokens = uriTokens[i].split("=");
    switch(valTokens[0]){
    case "utm_source":
        utmsource = valTokens[1];
        break;
    case "utm_medium":
        utmmedium = valTokens[1];
        break;
    case "utm_term":
        utmterm = valTokens[1];
        break;
    case "utm_content":
        utmcontent = valTokens[1];
        break;
    case "utm_campaign":
        utmcampaign = valTokens[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with Guava:

```
private static final String REFERRER = "referrer";
private static final String EQUALS = "%3D";
private static final String AMPERSAND = "%26";

Map<String, String> map = Splitter.on(AMPERSAND).withKeyValueSeparator(EQUALS)
            .split(intent.getStringExtra(REFERRER));
```